# Если нет записей не показывать код (foreach)

Tags: php, foreach

Как не отображать код, если нет записей в foreach.

```
<h4><?php echo trans('55');?></h4>
<div class="ci2">
    <ul class="ci">
    <?php $a = $module->pcity; foreach ($lastitem as $item){ ?>
        <?php if ($item['city'] == $a) { ?> 
           <li class="thumbnail col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-12">          
            <img class="img-responsive" src="/uploads/images/hotels/slider/thumbs/<?php echo $item['thumbnail_image'];?>" alt="<?php echo $item['hotel_title'];?>">
              <div class="caption">
                <p><a title="<?php echo $item['title'];?>" href="<?php echo $item['slug'];?>"><?php echo $item['title'];?></a></p>
               <?php  if($item['price'] > 0){ ?>
                <p class="lead"><?php echo $item['price'];?></small> </p>
               <?php } ?>
            </div>
           </li>
        <?php } ?>   
    <?php } ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Сейчас если нет записей, отображается этот код:

```
<h4><?php echo trans('55');?></h4>
<div class="ci2">
    <ul class="ci">
    </ul>
</div>
```

Пробовал все обвернуть в условие:

```
<?php if ($lastitem > 1) { ?>
// весь код
<?php }  ?>
```

Не помогает.

Что можно придумать? Или можно как-то вставить код (h3, div, ul) в foreach но при цикле не дублировать его?
Спасибо.

Comment: а почему `$lastitem > 1`, а не `$lastitem > 0` ? и вообще надо бы `count($lastitem) > 0`

Comment: тоже пробовал не помогает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

/* как я понял из дополнений, требуется что-то вроде этого */
/* код возможно не рабочий, но идея должна быть понятна */

// сначала фильтруем по нужному условию
if (!empty($lastitem)) {
  $a                     = $module->pcity;
  $filter_pcity_lastitem = [];

  foreach ($lastitem as $item) {
    if ($item['city'] == $a) {
      $filter_pcity_lastitem[] = $item;
    }
  }
}

?>

// потом проверяем, есть ли уже отфильтрованные результаты
<?php if (!empty($filter_pcity_lastitem)) { ?>
  <h4><?php echo trans('55'); ?></h4>
  <div class="ci2">
    <ul class="ci">
      <?php foreach ($filter_pcity_lastitem as $item){ ?>
      <li class="thumbnail col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-12">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="/uploads/images/hotels/slider/thumbs/<?php echo $item['thumbnail_image']; ?>"
             alt="<?php echo $item['hotel_title']; ?>">
        <div class="caption">
          <p><a title="<?php echo $item['title']; ?>"
                href="<?php echo $item['slug']; ?>"><?php echo $item['title']; ?></a></p>
          <?php if ($item['price'] > 0) { ?>
            <p class="lead"><?php echo $item['price']; ?></small> </p>
          <?php } ?>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <?php } ?>
  </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: !empty также пробовал, все равно выводит код (h4, div, ul). При этом содержимое li не выводится

Comment: 1. этот if(!empty($lastitem)) - заверни весь блок (h4, div, ul)
2. li у тебя только когда $item['city'] == $a, значит в $lastitem есть элементы без ['city']
3. сделай var_dump($lastitem) чтобы посмотреть, что там

Comment: отображает NULL. Скорее всего как вы написали в $lastitem есть элементы без ['city']. Можно как-то решить это?

Comment: отредактировал, попробуй, как я написал

Comment: если NULL, то элементов без city как раз нет, и !empty($lastitem) должен работать

Comment: Он NULL отображает если есть записи и если их нет. Сейчас попробую ваш код.

Comment: ты что-то не то вардампишь, или не в то время, сделай var_dump прямо перед кодом и проверь, нет ли опечаток

Comment: Большое спасибо! Все заработало с вашим кодом. Хорошего дня!